# Vector based on a set and in the order of another vector

Tags: vectors

This feels like a very basic question, so I hope I am not in the wrong place.

I have a set of (color, value) pairs `CV={(color_1,value_1), (color_2,value_2) ...}` and a vector of colors `color = [color_2, color_3, color_1,...]`.

I want to formally define the vector `Value` as the values in `CV` but in the order that the corresponding color appears in the `color` vector.

Is there a more mathematically exact way of writing this?

Example: `CV = {(orange, 7), (red, 3), (blue, 91), (green,22)}` and `color=[red, blue, green, orange]`. Now `Value` should be `Value = [3, 91, 22, 7]`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You just gave the definition.

Comment: thanks for the swift answer. My question would be: Is there a more mathematically exact way of writing this. Because right now it sounds a bit vague.

Comment: Not really. What you've said is precise. Given any CV and color, I can define Value precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CV defines a map mapping colors to values. Hence we can write $Value = (CV(color_i))_{i=1}^n$, where $n$ is the given dimension.